# group items with same value with that value as header

Tags: python, django, list

I'm practicing my python and django by making a recipe site.
I can add ingredients (class RecipeIngredient) per recipe using inlines, searching for ingredients i already have in my database (class Ingredient) (with nutrional facts etc). This results in one big list of ingredients per recipe.

To order them I added a step and a stepnum attribute. I return a list ordered by the stepnum, but how can I div them apart? For instance. If you make a cake you would have ingredients for the cake, and for the icing. all the ingredients for the icing would get a step value of "icing", and a stepnum of 0. all the ingredients for the cake would get a step value of "cake" and a stepnum of 1.

I would like all the ingredients with stepnum 1 to appear under one  that has the value associated with the items that have a stepnum value of 1, in this case "cake".

How?

I have this code on my recipedetail.html:

```
<div><h1> INGREDIENTS:  </h1></div>     
    <div>
    {% for ingredients in recipe.get_text %}

            <ul>

                {% for item in ingredients %}
                
        

                    <li><em>
                        {{item.1|safe}} {% if item.2 is not None %} {{item.2|safe}} {% endif %} {{ item.0|safe}}
                        
                    </em></li>

                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

and the function get_text:

```
def get_text(self):
    a = []
    ingredients = []
    for ingredient in self.RecipeIngredients.all():
        ingredients.append((ingredient.ingredientname, ingredient.amount, ingredient.unit, ingredient.step, ingredient.stepnum))
        ingredients.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[4])
    a.append(ingredients)
    
    return a
```

and my model:

```
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='RecipeIngredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ingredientname = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
step = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
stepnum = models.IntegerField(default="0")

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ingredientname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your model by adding:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['step', 'stepnum']
```

Or in views.py using group by.

Try to get the heavy lifting done before you get to the template.